# Cannot load the app in titanium android emulator

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, appcelerator

I am having this problem while running my application in emulator.When I run application it shows in console this error:

```
[ERROR]Error reading data file
```

and then nothing happens.Don't know what can be the issue, tried it many ways deleting all virtual AVDs and cleaning up the project again and again but not working anyway any solution for that? I am using 2.1.1 titanium SDK and android V8 (2.2).

sometime this also show this error in console:

```
[ERROR]No building apps, No launcher activity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the application run before?

Have you tried a clean build or deleting the build directory to perform a full rebuild? You can also have a look into the logcat provided by DDMS to search helpful information.

Comment: Actually manumaticx i have never gone through this issue so can you please explain the steps to get this issue resolved I have seen the ddms file in tools folder but not know what to do next with that after opening.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: After opening the tool you can select your connected device / emulator and it will you show all logs of the android system. This might help you with additional information, e.g. some exceptions that are not recognized by titanium.
But the first thing I would try is that complete clean rebuild of your app, in case your code is correct ;-)